# Xcode7 / iOS9: Unit Tests: iPhone Developer: ambiguous (matches "iPhone Developer: Max M. (Team A ID) and "iPhone Developer: Max M. (Team B ID))

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, code-signing

I'm working for two teams A and B. Therefore I need to create and install two development certificates. When I set "code signing identity" in Xcode's "build settings" to the general value "iOS Developer" my both team's **applications** are building and running without errors. But if I setup the same for my App's **unit tests** Xcode is not able to decide which of the two code signing identities it shall use and the following error is shown:

> iPhone Developer: ambiguous. (matches "iPhone Developer: Max M. (Team A ID) and "iPhone Developer: Max M. (Team B ID))

Answer (score 1):

The **application** is compiling, because there is a team id assigned to the application target. This team ID helps Xcode to select the right of the two code signing identity. But for my **unit tests** Xcode offers no possibility to assign a team. Subsequently it is not able to select the right one of my two code signing identities. These are possible solutions:

- Delete the code signing certificate of the other team: If I delete the code signing identity belonging to Team A, my Team B's application are building. But my Team A's solution will fail with a code signing error.
- Assign concrete code signing identities instead of the general "iOS Developer" identity: In that case everything is working for me, but for my team members the application is broken, because they have their own identities.
- Use only one developer certificate per team and use this to code sign the unit test target: At the moment my Team B's account has two team members which have their own developer certificate. I could delete my developer certificate and use the one of my college. But in that case I would need to transfer the related public and private keys from my colleges computer to mine.

All of these solutions are not brilliant. I think that this can be fixed by an Xcode update. Therefore I filed the radar [22941194](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4591953312219136).